# Django @ Google App Engine - Site Map Framework

Tags: django, google-app-engine

has anybody managed to get Djangos [site map framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) to run on Google App Engine?

I receive the following exception:

ImproperlyConfigured at /sitemap.xml

You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE setting yet.

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/sitemap.xml 
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured 
Exception Value: You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE setting yet. 
Exception Location: D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py in complain, line 13

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with GAE, but I may have a solution to your problem. Check out the Sitemap Framework docs @ http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

Look at both the *Simple Example* and the *Example*. The sitemap code takes a dict of name:SiteMap. Any valid Sitemap object will work. The minimum for a Sitemap class is to  define items(), which returns a list of objects that came from *somewhere*.

We have a StaticSitemap class which just reads a list of URLs from a file and returns that, plus it has a location(item) method that just returns the item (since it's a simple path).

Answer (score 1):

This fork of the helper has sitemaps working with GAE and the django helper.

http://code.google.com/p/dherbst-app-engine-django/wiki/Sitemaps

Answer (score 0):

Does not work on GAE. Star the issue here.

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=102&q=sitemaps